# Masking to input type text to only 4 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying restrict a user from entering more than 4 digits.

For that I am using:

```
$("#YEAR").mask("(9999)");
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'

Do I need to include a library for it?

Comment: Are you importing the `.mask` library after jQuery, and before your custom code?

Comment: I am not using any Library except jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: Do i need to use Any JQuery Masking Library?

Comment: yes since jquery doesn't have a mask `method` :)...  here you go https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ .Go through the documentation before you implement :)

Comment: Is it Licenced version?

Comment: You can review the license here: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/blob/master/LICENSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution could be:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#YEAR').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="YEAR" name="YEAR"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the char code range you're including/excluding?

Comment: @evolutionxbox If the user pressed a non number char it is escluded: return false.  The maxlegth property works for text input field. So this property limit to only 4 chars and the function limit the input to only digit.

Comment: What's the browser compatibility for the input maxlength attribute?

Comment: @evolutionxbox you may take a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input. Do you have problems?

Comment: No, no problems. (also, I found this http://caniuse.com/#feat=maxlength)